# Changing the font of atom label in rdkit

Tags: font-face, rdkit, cheminformatics

I'm trying to change the font type of the atom labels in RDKIT.
The default font type is 'sans'. I ran this code on colab:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw


smiles = 'C1=CC=C(C=C1)I'
mol = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)]

IPythonConsole.drawOptions.atomLabelFontFace = 'Times New Roman'

pic = Draw.MolsToGridImage(mol, returnPNG=False, subImgSize= (256, 256), molsPerRow=1)

display (pic)
```

But it seems that the font type doesn't change, neither when I tried other font types. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use `IPythonConsole.drawOptions.fontFile` to choose the font.

Times New Roman is not installed in Colab, so you have to install it or you can use the existing serif font (LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf).

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdDepictor, Draw
rdDepictor.SetPreferCoordGen(True)
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
IPythonConsole.molSize = (600, 300)

IPythonConsole.drawOptions.fontFile = r'/usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf'
IPythonConsole.drawOptions.explicitMethyl = True

m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CC(F)CC(Cl)C(C(=O)O)C(P)CC(S)CC(Br)CN') # Dummy molecule
rdDepictor.Compute2DCoords(m)
m
```

[image]

On your local computer you also need to set the path to the font:

`IPythonConsole.drawOptions.fontFile = r'C:\Windows\Fonts\times.ttf'`